# Queued messages + API endpoint

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, amazon-sqs

We have developed modular web app with very powerful API and now we need queuing tool for delayed|time consuming jobs. We are looking at RabbitMQ or AWS SQS. But these two just store messages, and you have to manually get messages from them or I misunderstood it?
 We would like to channel all messages through our API, so when message is published to Queue in should be POST-ed (after some delay) to to our Interface.

So my question:

- Is there any tool for queuing that support http post (with oauth2)?
- If not, is this approach somehow valid:

  - Create worker that poll messages from queue
    and POST them to API with some client?
    (we have to maintain cli tool, and we want to avoid that).
  - Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

When using SQS polling is the only way out.
To make things easier you can write this polling logic in AWS Lambda because lambda functions do not have the overhead of maintaining infrastructure and servers